# Java Generic Conversion not as expected

Tags: java, generics, type-conversion

If someone could resolve this puzzle for me. I am sure I am missing something !

```
interface a { }
class b implements a { }
class c extends ArrayList<b> { }
class d {
    d(ArrayList<a> param) {}
}

class e {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
         d newd = new d(new c());
    }
}
```

This code has an error:
Error   `d(ArrayList<a>) is not applicable (actual argument c cannot be converted to ArrayList<a> by method invocation conversion)`

Surely class `c` can be converted to `ArrayList<a>` as `c` extends `ArrayList<b>` and `b` implements `a` !
I have tried explicit conversion but it does not help.

It does not make sense either to change `class c extends ArrayList<b>` to `extends ArrayList<a>` as the purpose of `c` to to be a collection of `b` and the interface `a` is merely for display purposes. Also class `d` is a generic display class that relies on functionality expressed in the interface `a` and so makes no sense to change that either.

Advice would be handy !

Comment: You should use capitalized names for your classes, it is more difficult to read as it is.

Comment: Favor composition over inheritance (Effective Java 2 item 16).

Answer (score 3):

This should suit your needs:

```
class d {
    d(ArrayList<? extends a> param) {
    }
}
```

`c` isn't an `ArrayList<a>` but an `ArrayList<? extends a>` since `b` is a subtype of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that an ArrayList is not the same thing as an ArrayList, even if b extends A.  What would happen if D called param.add(new AImpl()), where AImpl was some other implementation of interface A?

For more details, see [The Java Generics Tutorial section on inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html).

(As an aside, it's also generally not a good idea to extend an ArrayList - most of the time, you want to be wrapping it, not extending it.)

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
d(ArrayList<? extends a> param) {}
```

ArrayList is not a subclass of ArrayList because the former can have a's added to it while the latter cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Please respect java naming conventions:

```
interface A {
}

class B implements A {
}

class C extends ArrayList<B> {
}

class D {

    D(ArrayList<A> param) {
    }
}

class E {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        D newd = new D(new C());
    }
}
```

So your assumption is that `ArrayList<B>` is castable to an `ArrayList<A>` as `B implements A`. This is not true, this is not how generics work. You simply cannot cast generic types.
Try doing something like:

```
final ArrayList<Object> myNewArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

To distill the problem.
You need to use [bounded type parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) to solve this. Changing your `D` class to:

```
class D {

    D(ArrayList<? extends A> param) {        
    }
}
```

Would make it work as now you're saying: I want a collection of any type as long as it's an `A`.